# A function in C that adds a node at the end of a singly linked list is not working

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I just wrote a function in C that is supposed to add a node at the end of a linked list, but when I compiled the program, I got nothing in the console. Here is the body of the function :

```
void addAtend(node *head, int val){
node *temp;
node *tempVal;
temp =head;
tempVal= (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
if(tempVal==NULL){
    printf("Error! Memory was not allocated!");
    exit(-1);
}
tempVal ->data=val;
tempVal->next=NULL;
while (temp!=NULL)
{
    temp = temp->next;

}
temp->next = tempVal;
```

}

**Here is the complete C program:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct linked {
    int data;
    struct linked *next;


} node;

//function to ietrate through a linked list
void printer(node *head){
    node *temp = head;
    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    
}

//function to add a value to the end of the linked list
void addAtend(node *head, int val){
    node *temp;
    node *tempVal;
    temp =head;
    tempVal= (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(tempVal==NULL){
        printf("Error! Memory was not allocated!");
        exit(-1);
    }
    tempVal ->data=val;
    tempVal->next=NULL;
    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;

    }
    temp->next = tempVal;
    


}

int main(){

    node *ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(ptr==NULL){
        printf("Error!");
        exit(-1);
    }
    node *head;
    head = ptr;
    
    ptr->data = 30;
    ptr->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->next->data =50;
    ptr->next->next = NULL;


    addAtend(head, 40);
    printer(head);

}
```

**The output looks like this:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCd2R.png)

Could anyone look at this code and tell me what's wrong with function?

Comment: `while (temp!=NULL)`. When that loop finishes `temp` will be `NULL`, so the line that follows the loop will dereference a NULL pointer, which (on most systems) causes a segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After this loop

```
while (temp!=NULL)
{
    temp = temp->next;

}
```

the pointer `temp` is equal to `NULL`. So this null pointer is used to access memory in this statement

```
temp->next = tempVal;
```

that results in undefined behavior.

The function can be defined the following way

```
int addAtend( node **head, int val )
{
    node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = val;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function can be called for example like

```
addAtend( &head, 40 );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct linked {
    int data;
    struct linked *next;
} node;

int addAtend( node **head, int val )
{
    node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = val;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

FILE * printer( const node *head, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", head->data );
    }
    
    fputs( "null", fp );
    
    return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    node *head = NULL;
    
    addAtend( &head, 30 );
    addAtend( &head, 40 );
    addAtend( &head, 50 );
    
    fputc( '\n', printer( head, stdout ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
30 -> 40 -> 50 -> null
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I have a quick question: In the addAtend(), you wrote:

`node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;```
Doesn't  `int success = new_node != NULL;` assign a pointer to a variable of type `int`?

Comment: @Owais This declaration of the variable success can be equivalently rewritten like int success = ( new_node != NULL ); So the value of the variable success is either 1 if new_node != NULL or 0 otherwise.